# Importing Excel format data into R/R Studio and using glmnet package?

Tags: r, data, regularization, excel, error-handling

I have no problem importing Excel formatted data into R/R Studio and use all other R packages that I use.  But, when I want to use the glmnet package to develop a regularization model, I invariably run into the following error (after specifying my regularization model and attempting to run it):

```
Error in storage.mode(y) <- "double":
  (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'
```

Here is what I have already tried to resolve this:

1. De-format the numbers in Excel (no scientific notation, no %, etc.)
2. Did copy-paste-special values several times
3. At time of importing the spreadsheet, converted every column from "include" to "numeric" type
4. After importing the data, converting it to a matrix.

But, none of the above have eliminated the error.

Comment: Are you using an excel file or a CSV file?

Comment: How exactly do you import the data?   Where exactly does the error arise?  It hints that your dependent variable is a list and not a number, and this is likely due to some sort of data import problems, either on R  side or excel side

Comment: i am using an Excel file, and using the standard R Studio import Excel file facility.  I am not sure why Y would be a list as I changed the data set to a matrix.  But, other colleagues have reviewed my codes and I think I may have done an error in naming my data reference when converting the Y data to a matrix.  I will work on that and keep you posted.  Your suggestions to review my data import and data references are helpful.

Answer (score 0):

After soliciting assistance from many colleagues, I found the answer to my problem.  And, I thought it be worth sharing.  glmnet package requires that you format your data as matrix.

What I had already done is import and transform the data as matrix as follows:

```
data.matrix(data)
```

But, that is not enough.  You still have to convert the X and Y arrays as matrix as follows:

a) First do the x matrix: 
`x = as.matrix(data,...)`;
b) Second do the y matrix: y = `as.matrix(data,...)`.

Once I did the above change the glmnet package seems to work just fine.

I am unclear why the glmnet package is so much more sensitive to how much you matricize your data.  But, that is the way it is.